# How to run a model without having to run the training data again

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm currently using TensorFlow and KERAS on PyCharm. Every time I want to use a model I have to run the training data again then in the same script then run the testing data. How would I run the training data once, and then I can go on whenever I want and run testing data through the model and it will still work. Ie. Developing a model to recognise images, how would I run the program whenever I want to recognise images, instead of having to run the training data and then recognise images in the same script.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, by saving and then loading your model.

Here's a link to the documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Saving and loading only the weights will make this process more efficient if you already have the structure in your code that makes the prediction. So you might want to look into that too.